# Solving trigonometric equation : confusion in putting values.

Tags: trigonometry

This is the equation in triangle ABC `cosA = sinB / (2 sinC)`, then the triangle is,

(a) Isosceles

(b) Equilateral

(c) Right

(d) None

Solution-

[image]

I solved the question in the same way but in the end, I observed that the if I put all angles equal to 60 degrees then the equation is satisfied so I changed my answer to equilateral.

I have solved a lot of competitive questions using this trick, why am I wrong here?

Comment: $\angle A=\angle B=\angle C=60^\circ$ isn't the only solution of the equation. For instance, $(\angle A, \angle B, \angle C)=(45^\circ, 90^\circ, 45^\circ)$ also works.

Comment: You've noted that the equation is true when the triangle is equilateral, but you haven't proven that the equation is always false when the triangle *isn't* equilateral.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Note that according to the standard grouping of operations, $\sin B / 2 \sin C = \frac{\sin B}2 \sin C,$ which is not what you want. That should be another motivation to learn how to typeset formulas better.

Answer (score 1):

You know that if a triangle satisfies the equation, the triangle must be isosceles.
Here is a proof that **any** non-degenerate isosceles triangle with congruent sides $\overline{BC}$ and $\overline{AB}$ satisfies the equation.

[image]

Let $\triangle ABC$ be isosceles such that $BC = AB.$
Without loss of generality we can assume $AB = 1.$
Let $D$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AC}$.
Then $AD = CD = \cos A$ and $BD = \sin C.$
Put $E$ on the line $\overline{AB}$ (extended as shown in the figure, if necessary)
so that $\angle AEC$ is a right angle; then $CE = \sin B.$

Using $AC = 2\cos A$ as the base of the triangle and $BD = \sin C$ as the altitude,
the area of the triangle is $\frac12(2\cos A)\sin C = \cos A \sin C.$

But using $AB = 1$ as the base of the triangle and $CD = \sin B$ as the altitude,
the area of the triangle is $\frac12\sin B.$

Therefore $\cos A \sin C = \frac12\sin B.$
Provided the triangle is non-degenerate, so that all angles are defined and
$\sin C \neq 0,$ we can rewrite this equation as

$$ \cos A = \frac{\sin B}{2 \sin C} $$

exactly as required.